# Accessing current_user in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am trying to access attributes about the current_user inside my controllers.

```
class MatchfinderController < ApplicationController

  def c(value, t_array)
    t_array.min{|a,b|  (value-a).abs <=> (value-b).abs }
  end

  def show 
    peeps = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id])
    user_a = []

    peeps.each do |user|  
      user_a.push user.rating    
    end

    closest_rating = c(current_user.rating, user_a)

    @opponent = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ? AND rating = ? ", current_user.id, closest_rating])
  end
end
```

current_user is working in the view just fine however returns nil in the controller.

Here is my SessionsHelper.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

The SessionsHelper is included by ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Here is my SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies[:remember_token] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm that cookies[:remember_token] is present and correct and exists in in the User table?

Comment: yes. It is being saved to the User table. All tests are passing except when I call current_user.rating in controller (NoMethodError).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your code in application controller and mark it as `helper_method` in this way you can use that method in both `helper` as well as `controller`

```
helper_method :current_user

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think helpers are only available to the view. Try putting this near the top of your controller:

`include SessionsHelper`

Comment: edited my post, SessionsHelper is already included in ApplicationController

Comment: If you call sign_in in the view, then that's why. Note that current user is found by looking at the cookies, and the remember token cookie is set in sign_in. I'm assuming this is only a problem on first access, though.

Comment: I don't call it in the view, I call create in SessionsController. I have included it above.

Comment: Assuming that cookies[] works in the obvious way.... sorry, I'm stumped. Find out if cookies[] actually contains what you think it does, examine the SQL generated in the current_user method. That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: yeah cookies are working. Sign in/out is working and managing state in views. It is just this controller that I am having trouble with. Thanks anyways!